# Bulk indexing using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Till now i was indexing data to elastic document by document and now as the data started increasing it has become very slow and not an optimized approach. So i was searching for a bulk insert thing and found Elastic Bulk API. From the documents in their official site i got confused. The approach i am using is by passing the data as WebRequest and executing them in the elastic server. So while creating a batch/bulk insert request the API wants us to form a template like

```
localhost:9200/_bulk as URL and 
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

to index a document with id 1 and field1 values as value 1. Also the API suggests to send the data as JSON (unpretty, to maintain a non escaping character or so). So to pass multiple document with multiple properties how can i structure my data.

I tried like this in FF RestClient , with POST and header as JSON , but RestClient is throwing some error and i know its not a valid JSON

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "indexName", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "111" },
{ "Name" : "CHRIS","Age" : "23" },"Gender" : "M"}
```

Comment: You don't need the comma after the first line and you're missing a closing `}` on the first line. Also you have a closing `}` in the middle of your second line, you need to remove it as well.

Comment: As Val, we need to add one more line at the end of script!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your data is not well-formed:

1. You don't need the comma after the first line
2. You're missing a closing `}` on the first line
3. You have a closing `}` in the middle of your second line you need to remove it as well.

The correct way of formatting your data for a bulk insert look like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk -d '
{ "index" : { "_index" : "indexName", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "111" }}
{ "Name" : "CHRIS","Age" : "23" ,"Gender" : "M"}
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson'
```

This will work.

**UPDATE**

Using Postman on Chrome it looks like this. Make sure to add a new line after line 2:

[image]

Comment: Val, am sorry for providing wrong input in my question. I will try and will let you know for sure. :)

Comment: i tried via rest client of FF and it threw bad request, Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;

Comment: How did you try it? Note that the **content is not JSON** but a custom format (so you cannot use a JSON header). Can you share a screenshot? Can you try a curl directly in your shell?

Comment: Hi, it worked!!! Thanks. I guess it was some RestClient issue. i took a new tab gave the contents and also i gave the content type as JSON and seems to be working fine. :)

Comment: Is it possible to delete a type in Elastic. I found after 1.5.4 version its no longer possible, just to make sure

Answer (score 9):

Using the elasticsearch 7.9.2

In order to send the bulk update I was getting the error of new line as below

**Failed update without new line**

[image]

This is wierd but after adding the new line in the last of the all the operations it is working fine with postman, notice line number 5 in below screenshot

**bulk update success after adding newline in last of all the commands in postman**

[image]