# How to insert a json log into an existing elasticsearch index using postman

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, insert, postman, kibana

I am very new to Elasticsearch and not very technical but I have been asked to insert some log files into Elasticsearch to view on Kibana.

I used postman to create an 'index' with the following  http://localhost:9200/testlogs/doc_

and the body of this request contained:

{
    "message": " Calculations execution ended",
    "level": "Information",
    "timeStamp": "2019-02-01T14:19:36.035679+00:00",
    "processName": "Calculations",
    "processVersion": "1.0.6941.27985",
    "fileName": "Calculations",
    "jobId": "13dde582-59f4-4540-abe4-98e87036eaa1",
}

this successfully inserted the json as I could view it on the Discover page.

The trouble I am having is inserting more logs into the existing index which is called 'testlogs'. How can I insert more logs into this index using postman?

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35845007/4604579

Comment: You can try bulk insert API if you have the whole data in JSON format. You can use CURL for this.

Comment: Sathishkumar Rakkiasamy - how would I do this? is this from the command line?