# Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Array ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am creating bulk request to the elastic search but got the error which specified in the title
Can any one check my JSON maybe this is not right

```
{ "index" :{ "_index" : "type", "_type" : "type", "_id" : "1" }}
{"type": "Variable", "processDefinitionKey":"Variable1", "products":[
{ "index" :{ "_index" : "new_type", "_type" : "new_type", "_id" : "1" }}
{ "code": "20", "type": "Variable", "name": "Integer"}]}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma at the end of the third line?

Comment: You need to make sure to have a new line character at the end of the last line. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35845007/4604579

Comment: This suggestions did not help me to solve the question of Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Array ElasticSearch

Comment: @Val I deleted all my indexes from array but after that i got other error Malformed action/metadata line [3], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the problem is that the document seems to be split between lines 2 and 4 and both of them are incomplete

```
{ "index" :{ "_index" : "type", "_type" : "type", "_id" : "1" }}
{"type": "Variable", "processDefinitionKey":"Variable1", "products":[
{ "index" :{ "_index" : "new_type", "_type" : "new_type", "_id" : "1" }}
{ "code": "20", "type": "Variable", "name": "Integer"}]}
```

Your document is actually this

```
{"type": "Variable", "processDefinitionKey":"Variable1", "products":[
```

Plus this

```
{ "code": "20", "type": "Variable", "name": "Integer"}]}
```

But it is split between two lines with `index` commands inbetween... That doesn't work.

It should look like this instead:

```
{ "index" :{ "_index" : "type", "_type" : "type", "_id" : "1" }}
{"type": "Variable", "processDefinitionKey":"Variable1", "products":[{ "code": "20", "type": "Variable", "name": "Integer"}]}
{ "index" :{ "_index" : "new_type", "_type" : "new_type", "_id" : "1" }}
{"type": "Variable", "processDefinitionKey":"Variable1", "products":[{ "code": "20", "type": "Variable", "name": "Integer"}]}
```

You need to make sure that:

- the JSON document stands on a single line (not multiple)
- each JSON document has a corresponding command line
- the last line is terminated by a newline character (not visible above because of SO formatting)